# Azure media service. How to stream from web browser

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-media-player

I am new to video streaming and trying to implement simple app to stream video from web browser.

I decided to use Azure Media Service for this purpose and found a lot of tutorials on their side how to stream to Chanel using desktop encoders like OBS, wirecast etc...

What I want to achieve is to stream video from web browser using webcam. I am trying to find if there is some solution for Azure Media Service or everything has to be implemented from scratch.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You will need support for RTMP streaming for this. RTMP streaming support isn't natively supported in browsers. One approach is to use a web application with RTMP relay support - e.g. restream.io - as this allows use of a streaming protocol (e.g. WebRTC) that is natively supported in the browser to send the stream out which can then be converted to RTMP by a web service. If you have a need to build your own web application, you would need to implement this essentially from scratch and can leverage a streaming media application framework such as GStreamer for this.